# No Simple Install For Lynx Browser?

Tags: apt, lynx

I was trying to get Lynx (a text browser) installed using the suggested route from [this article](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2022/262/Bash-Web-Scraping).

```
$ sudo apt install lynx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package lynx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lynx' has no installation candidate
$
```

I get the same response using `apt-get install` so there is something fundamentally wrong here.

Maybe the article was written before the lynx package was removed from apt ?

Comment: Lynx was not removed. The `lynx` package is in the Ubuntu 'universe' repository. See [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Thanks. Though I had universe installed but hadn't.